# What are general tips for generating grammars for context free languages?

Tags: soft-question, intuition, formal-languages, regular-language, context-free-grammar

Perhaps, this does not have a "correct" answer, but what are general tips for creating context free grammars for context free languages? I know there is usually no step by step solution to generate these grammars, but there must be some general tips to guide one to create them.

If you are keen on explaining by example, this is the language I am having trouble with:

$
L = \{0^p1^q0^r1^s : p + q = r + s \} 
$

I am not interested in the grammar to the above language, rather, I am interested in the process of creating grammars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest starting with a high level description of the language.

edit: I used this language instead of the language in the question.
$L=\{0^p1^q0^r1^s:p+r=q+s\}$

For example with L as defined above I would describe the language as "all bitstrings with equal number of 0s and 1s such that if partitioned into the longest substrings of all 0s and longest substrings of all 1s will have a maximum of 4 partitions, and if the bitstring is partitioned into 4 substrings, then the first substring must be 0s."

From there you can choose to build the language either top down or bottom up. It's not always clear which of those two options is easiest, but I often use the bottom up approach.

In the bottom up approach you start with a base case or with base cases. So here you would use the empty string as your base case.

$T\rightarrow\lambda$

Then you would consider what you could do to build out more of the language while staying within the confines of the language.

$Q\rightarrow SRS$

$R\rightarrow1R0|T$

$S\rightarrow0S1|T$

$T\rightarrow\lambda$

And if needed continue building upwards until you have enough to generate the entire language.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, how does the top down approach work? And also, assuming your start variable is $Q$, doesn't your grammar generate $01 \: 10 \: 0011 \not\in L$ (spaces to indicate $S$, $R$, $S$)?

Comment: Ah, I misread the exponents. My mistake. So my description then is incorrect and that cascades down to everything else.

Comment: I just edited my answer to make it correct, though by defining L as I mistakenly read yours to be.

Comment: For a top down approach you would start with trying to think of the largest structures you see in the patterns of the bitstrings first, and start the building from there. This can be useful if you want to do something like the language $L=\{0^k:k=2^n\}$

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I just tried the language you had, and the bottom up approach works nicely, but you'll have have at least one more statement in your language than in the one I worked out. A key insight is that since you want the length of $0^p1^q$ to be the same as the length of $0^r1^s$, bits must always come in pairs of two. However yours requires that the string be able to "grow" both from the middle as in my example and also from the ends.